# Alamofire fails with SSL error code: -1200

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am connecting to a self-signed URL and hence I have configured to disable the SSL cert evaluation for this URL. I am using Alamofire for my network operations.

```
static let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = NetworkConfiguration.sessionTimeoutInterval
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "xyz.com:12345" : .disableEvaluation
    ]
    let trustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration, serverTrustPolicyManager: trustPolicyManager)
}()
```

I have also disabled ATS in my info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

This is how I connect to API service:

```
        WebService.sessionManager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: resource.method.encodingFormat(), headers: headers)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON { response in

                let requestAPI = response.request?.url?.absoluteString
                print("**********network Manager request: \(requestAPI ?? "request not found") ")

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let json = response.data {
                        print("############Network Manager response: \(String(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "Response Data could not be printed")")
                        completion(json, nil)
                    } else {
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    let errorFailureCode = (error as NSError).code
                    print("Network manager failure with reason: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completion(nil, error)
                }

        }
```

Despite this, I am getting the error:

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9800)
>       Task <68BD48CA-81E0-427C-B37F-50091A66EC7C>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9800])
>       Alamofire error - An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

Comment: okay, removed!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove port from the host string.

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
    "xyz.com" : .disableEvaluation
]
```

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick Are you able to connect from another client, e.g. Postman/web browser/curl?

Comment: I found the issue after breaking my head for few hours :( It was actually an issue from server. So, nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: Don't know whether I should delete the question OR add as an answer?